# 'FindFit' ignoring certain data points to optimise r^2 value

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

As shown in the code below,

```
datax = {0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 
   0.009, 0.01, 0.011};
datay = {0.067361, 0.057375, 0.043718, 0.031625, 0.026091, 0.021463, 
   0.017203, 0.014835, 0.012202, 0.010441, 0.008802};
dataxy = Transpose[{datax, datay}];
model = (Subscript[\[Mu], 0] i R^2)/(
   2 (y^2 + R^2)^(3/2)) /. {Subscript[\[Mu], 0] -> 4 \[Pi]*10^-7, 
    R -> 0.0065};
s = FindFit[dataxy, model, {{i}}, y]
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[dataxy, model, {{i}}, y]

p1 = ListPlot[dataxy, PlotStyle -> Red];
p2 = Plot[model /. s, {y, 0, 0.011}];
Show[p1, p2]
```

Mathematica outputs that the optimal value of `i` would be `{i -> 639.813}`. However, when I tried to fit for `i` using Desmos with `i=700`, the fit seems to be better.
[image]

Meanwhile, an `i` value of `639` gives the following graph.
[image]

Is it possible to make mathematica not ignore any of the data points just to optimise the R^2 value? Thank you.

Comment: Mathematica is not ignoring any data points: it is optimizing the sum of the squares of the discrepancies between the calculated and experimental values. Your curve is, unfortunately, not a great fit for this data with the parameter values you gave.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you draw the plot a bit less squeezed along the horizontal axis it looks like:

[image]

The blue curve is from MMA and the orange one from you. Although your curves fits the first 2 points better it is far worse for the other points. In fact, the error square sum for the first and second curve are:

```
{0.000157719, 0.000269005}
```

You see, the squared error sum is smaller for the MMA curve.

If you want to fit the first 2 points better, you may use a weighted fit.